# C & lua metatable for object oriented access

Tags: c, lua

I have something like this:
(Its actually C++ but in this simplified form there's nothing C++ specific in it)

```
struct Blob;

// Some key-value accessors on Blob
char * blob_get_value( Blob * b, char * key );
void set_value( Blob * b, char * key, char * value); 


//Some lua wrappers for these functions
int blob_get_value_lua( lua_State * L );
int blob_set_value_lua( lua_State * L );
```

I make these accessible in a syntactically clean way. Currently I expose the Blob object as a userdata and plug get and set into the metatable, using this I can do:

```
blob = Blob.new()
blob:set("greeting","hello")
print( blob:get("greeting") )
```

But I'd prefer

```
blob = Blob.new()
blob.greeting = hello
print( blob.greeting )
```

I know this can be done by setting the `__index` to `blob_get_value_lua` and `__newindex` to `blob_set_value_lua`. However making this change will break backward compatibility.

Is there any easy way to have both syntaxes at the same time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as you will keep `get` and `set` functions, both approaches will work.

If your object is a regular Lua table, both `__index` and `__newindex` will be called only for non-existant keys.

If your object (as you state in the update) is an userdata, you can simulate this behaviour yourself. In `__index`, if the key is `"get"` or `"set"`, return an appropriate function.

Comment: Thanks, but in my case Blob.new() creates a new userdata object, not a table, and get and set are going in the userdata's metatable. I'll update the question to be explicit about that.